# Prevent refreshing when submitting on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a HTML project. It gets a stock price via an API and jQuery. However when I try to submit with the `<form>` attribute it refreshes the page. How can I prevent the refresh?

addStock(); does a simple jQuery request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Stock Market Game PRE ALPHA BETA</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="addStock()">
    </form>


    <input type="text" name="stock">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Price">
  </body>
```

... rest of my code and addStock()

```
</html>
```

If you want my code for addStock() this is it:

```
<script>
    var Market = {};
    var Stocks = [];
    Market.GetQuote = function(ssymbol, fCallback) {
        this.symbol = ssymbol;
        this.fCallback = fCallback;
        this.DATA_SRC = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp";
        this.makeRequest();
    }
    Market.GetQuote.prototype.handleSuccess = function(jsonResult) {
        this.fCallback(jsonResult);
    }
    Market.GetQuote.prototype.handleError = function(jsonResult) {
        console.error(jsonResult);
    }
    Market.GetQuote.prototype.makeRequest = function() {
        //Abort any open requests
        if (this.xhr) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
        //Start a new request
        this.xhr = $.ajax({
            data: {
                symbol: this.symbol
            },
            url: this.DATA_SRC,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: this.handleSuccess,
            error: this.handleError,
            context: this
        });
    };
    function addStock() {
        var xForm = document.forms[0];
        var xField = xForm.elements[0];
        alert("Stock: " + xField.value);

        Stocks.push(new Market.GetQuote(xField.value.toString(), function jsonResult() {
            //Gotta catch all the errors
            if (!jsonResult || jsonResult.Message) {
                console.error("Error: ", jsonResult.Message);
                return;
            }
            //If it works lets return that json!
            return jsonResult;


        }));
        alert(new Market.GetQuote(xField.value, function jsonResult() {
            if (!jsonResult || jsonResult.Message) {
                console.error("Error: ", jsonResult.Message);
                return;
            }
            console.log(jsonResult);
            return jsonResult[2];

        }));


      new Markit.QuoteService(xField.value, function (jsonResult) {

//Catch errors
if (!jsonResult || jsonResult.Message) {
    console.error("Error: ", jsonResult.Message);
    return;
}
//If all goes well, your quote will be here.
console.log(jsonResult);

/**
* Need help? Visit the API documentation at:
* http://dev.markitondemand.com
*/
});
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) attached to `input type="submit"` where `events` is `"click"` for event attribute `onsubmit`; using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) within `handler` to prevent default action of `form` submission

See [4.10.22.3 Form submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm)

> Each `form` element has a **planned navigation**, which is either null or a
>   [task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task); when the `form` is first created, its [planned navigation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#planned-navigation) must be
>   set to null. In the behaviours described below, when the user agent is
>   required to plan to navigate to a particular resource destination, it
>   must run the following steps:
>
> 1. If the form has a non-null planned navigation, remove it from its
>      task queue.
> 2. Let the form's planned navigation be a new task that consists of
>      running the following steps:
>
>    1. Let the form's planned navigation be null.
>    2. [Navigate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#navigate) target browsing context to destination. If replace is true, then target browsing context must be navigated with replacement
>         enabled.
>
>    For the purposes of this task, target browsing context and replace are the variables that were set up when the overall form submission
>      algorithm was run, with their values as they stood when this planned
>      navigation was queued.
>
>    3. Queue the task that is the form's new planned navigation.
>
> The task source for this task is the DOM manipulation task source.
>
> The behaviours are as follows:
>
> **Mutate action URL** Let query be the result of encoding the form data set using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding
>   algorithm, interpreted as a US-ASCII string.
>
> Set parsed action's query component to query.
>
> Let destination be a new URL formed by applying the URL serialiser
>   algorithm to parsed action.
>
> [Plan to navigate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#plan-to-navigate) to destination.

html

```
<form>    
    <input type="text" name="stock">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Price">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("input[type=submit]").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  addStock()
})
```